# Approximation entropy at $T + dT$

Tags: thermodynamics, differentiation, calculus, approximations

I have seen this approximation for a little change of temperature, but I don't understand how we got this result. I don't understand how we did this approximation mathematically.

$dS = \frac{-dQ}{T+dT} = \frac{-dQ}{T}(1 + \frac{dT}{T})^{-1} = - \frac{dQ}{T}$

Is it possible to have more details on why this post has been closed? I read the help center and I thought this question was about "Mathematics in the context of physics".

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+series+of+1%2F%281%2Bx%29 just the taylor series of 1/(1+x) and assume that dT<<T

Answer (score 1):

> I have seen this approximation for a little change of temperature, but I don't understand how we got this result. I don't understand how we did this approximation mathematically.

> $dS = \frac{-dQ}{T+dT} = \frac{-dQ}{T}(1 + \frac{dT}{T})^{-1} = - \frac{dQ}{T}$

This seems to be showing you how to expand $1/(1+dT/T)$ for small $dT/T$ and further what it means to neglect terms higher order than linear in "small" quantities.

Here, we are considering $\delta Q$ and $\delta T$ to be "small" (in some sense that we do not feel compelled to define crisply).

$$
\frac{-dQ}{T}\left(1 + \frac{dT}{T}\right)^{-1} = \frac{-dQ}{T}\left(1 - \frac{dT}{T}+O(dT^2)\right)\;,
$$
where the $O(dT^2)$ symbol means terms of order $dT^2$ and higher.

Then:
$$
 \frac{-dQ}{T}\left(1 - \frac{dT}{T}+O(dT^2)\right) = \frac{-dQ}{T} + O(dTdQ)\;,
$$
where the $O(dTdQ)$ means terms of order $dQdT$ and higher (in the small quantities).

---

If you are interested in why:
$$
\frac{1}{1+x} = 1 - x+ O(x^2)\;,
$$
you can show that this is true via the usual Taylor/MacLaurin series expansion.

Given:
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x}\;,
$$
we have:
$$
f'(x) = (-1)\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}
$$

And so:
$$
f(0) = 1
$$
and
$$
f'(0) = -1
$$

The Taylor series expansion about zero (MacLaurin series) is:
$$
f(x) = f(0) + f'(0)x + \frac{1}{2!}f''(0)x^2 + \ldots\;.
$$
So:
$$
\frac{1}{1+x} = 1 - x + x^2 +\ldots
$$

Comment: +1. I'm wondering why the author of the original derivation didn't use $dT\ll T$ to go directly from $-dQ/(T+dT)$ to $-dQ/T$?

Comment: Effectively that is what the author is doing, but just being very explicit about it... I guess... OP didn't really provide much context...

Comment: @Chemomechanics I was wondering that as well. Seems to be an overly complicated exercise, even if practicing Taylor expansions is the intention.